# Get the Readable Message from ManagementObject.InvokeMethod

Tags: window, .net-2.0, wmi, .net-1.1

Is there any way to get the Message Text from the return value of WMI InvokeMethod e.g. for the following code

```
ManagementBaseObject outParam = nicMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", newGateway, null);
int result = outParam["ReturnValue"];
```

Microsoft has published [return values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Is there anyway to get the readable message from the return values instead creating hardcoded return value and message dictionary.

note: Please give me something which can work in .net 2.0 (and/or .net 1.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the description of the value returned by the `SetGateWays` method using the  [`ValueMap and Value Qualifiers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

[image]

Try this sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<String> LValues = new List<String>();
            List<String> LValuesDesc = new List<String>();
            Dictionary<String, String> LValuesDict = new Dictionary<String, String>();

            ManagementClass WClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
            WClass.Options.UseAmendedQualifiers = true;
            foreach (MethodData md in WClass.Methods)
            {
                if (md.Name.Equals("SetGateways"))
                {

                    //fill a list with the ValuesMap
                    foreach (QualifierData q in md.Qualifiers)
                    {
                        if (q.Name.Equals("ValueMap"))
                        {
                            foreach (object Value in ((Array)q.Value))
                            {
                                LValues.Add(Convert.ToString(Value));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //fill a list with the Values
                    foreach (QualifierData q in md.Qualifiers)
                    {
                        if (q.Name.Equals("Values"))
                        {
                            foreach (object Value in ((Array)q.Value))
                            {
                                LValuesDesc.Add(Convert.ToString(Value));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                //Merge both lists in a dictionary
                for (int i = 0; i <= LValues.Count - 1; i++)                
                    LValuesDict.Add(LValues[i], LValuesDesc[i]);                

                }

            }

                //Get the description of some return values
                Console.WriteLine(LValuesDict["1"]);
                Console.WriteLine(LValuesDict["64"]);
                Console.WriteLine(LValuesDict["77"]);
                Console.WriteLine(LValuesDict["91"]);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer i would test this and will mark it answer. But can you please tell me from where you took the first Picture?

Comment: The image is from the [`WMI Delphi Code Creator`](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/)